# customized alertbox for iphone mobile web

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, mobile-website

I want to change the "yes" / "no" button which comes up for javascript alertbox in mobile web. Is that possible ? do mobile safari has options to change the text in the default javascript alertbox ? or is there any 3rd party javascrript apis which can do this thing ?

[image]

I am not able to create a alertbox like showed in this screenshot.

Comment: Out of interest, is this iOS 2 running on your iPhone? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, sorry. I am not sure if you are familiar with `Objective-C`, but the whole dialog is created by hardcoded means. Only the `message` property of the alert box is passed to the alert by the so called `UIWebView`.